# Build of guile-2.0.11 on macOS Sierra fails: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, macos, macos-sierra

I am not an experienced programmer/developer/software engineer, but I need to get this older version of guile-2.0.11 built "by hand" rather than using home-brew (which installs the latest version of guile). I downloaded the tarball for guile-2.0.11 from the GitHub repository, extracted it and ran the shell script autogen.sh. This produced a configure executable which ran to completion and generated a Makefile.  When I run make, the build continues until I get the this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_clock_getcpuclockid", referenced from:
_scm_init_stime in libguile_2.0_la-stime.o
"_ffi_call", referenced from:
 _scm_i_foreign_call in libguile_2.0_la-foreign.o
```

and 16 more "*ffi*" similar messages.  Then the error messages finishes

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see      invocation)
make[3]: *** [libguile-2.0.la] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

The linker apparently can't find these symbols.  The explicit link command is quite extensive..it shows all the options, include and library paths if I use "make V=1".  Here is the beginning, showing the options and paths:

```
Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -  I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/include -  I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -  I/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.8.1/include -D_THREAD_SAFE  -Wall -  Wmissing-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wpointer-arith -Wswitch-  enum -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fvisibility=hidden -  I/usr/local/Cellar/bdw-gc/7.6.0/include -g -O2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/bdw-  gc/7.6.0/lib -lgc -L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib                -liconv -  L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -lintl -R/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -Wl,-  framework -Wl,CoreFoundation -L/usr/local/lib -lunistring -R/usr/local/lib        -version-info 29:2:7 -export-dynamic -no-undefined   -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib     -L/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.8.1/lib -o libguile-2.0.la -rpath /usr/local/lib
```

Then there is libtool.

```
libtool: link: gcc -dynamiclib  -o .libs/libguile-2.0.22.dylib    .libs/libguile_2.0_la-alist.o .libs/libguile_2.0_la-arbiters.o   .libs/libguile_2.0_la-array-handle.o
```

and many many more xxxx.o

then

```
-Wl,-force_load,../lib/.libs/libgnu.a  -L/usr/local/Cellar/bdw-  gc/7.6.0/lib -lgc -L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib   -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -  L/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.8.1/lib -lintl -lunistring -liconv -lgmp -  lltdl -lm  -g -O2 -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation   -install_name    /usr/local/lib/libguile-2.0.22.dylib -compatibility_version 30 - current_version 30.2 -Wl,-single_module
```

The up-to-date version of ffilib is in the symlink /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib which is in the ld path, so I would think that the linker could find it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found the solution to part of this problem.  All the undefined symbols related to _ffi_ are due to a linker flag omission.  The answer is here, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062678/where-are-ffi-symbols-defined/45103652#45103652).  However the first error related to "_clock_getcpuclockid" still prevents the build.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is really two problems: (1) the undefined symbol "_clock_getcpuclockid" and (2) all the "*ffi*" undefined symbols.  The answer to the second problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062678/where-are-ffi-symbols-defined) and the answer to the first problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104102/how-to-fix-libguile-stime-c-on-macos-sierra-build-of-guile-2-0-11). There may be other solutions but these resulted in the installation of guile-2.0.11 on my macOS Sierra (10.12.5),