# How to fix libguile/stime.c on macOS Sierra build of guile-2.0.11?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, guile

[enter link description here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-guile/2016-06/msg00252.html)The build of guile-2.0.11 stops with the following error,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_clock_getcpuclockid", referenced from:
  _scm_init_stime in libguile_2.0_la-stime.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see      invocation)
```

Googling around I found a bug report and patch.  The bug report is here:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-guile/2016-06/msg00252.html

The link to the patch is in the bug report.  The patch is just a few lines so I just edited stime.c by incorporating the patch into stime.c, ran configure again and make again.  Unfortunately the error remains unchanged.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently that patch has been superseded: [see this post at bug-guile](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-guile/2017-03/msg00000.html)

Since the problem with stime.c has been fixed in subsequent Guile versions, I simply copied a later version of stime.c in the libguile directory (.../libguile/stime.c) and moved the original package version to stime_old.c.  Then configure and make.  The error no longer appears and the make runs to completion.  I then did sudo make install and it appears to be ok.